# Laravel blade custom directive with include partial

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a custom Blade directive from which I'm trying to include a partial with the Blade syntax `@include()`. The problem is that I have a custom views namespace:

```
\Blade::directive('name', function() {
    $viewsNamespace = 'viewsNameSpace::';
    $formPartial = $viewsNamespace . 'partials._form';
    return "{{ @include({$formPartial}) }}";
});
```

**This outputs the error,**

> `Class 'viewsNameSpace' not found`

because its interpreting `viewsNameSpace::` as a class.

This outputs just the string without parsing it:

```
return "@include('{$formPartial}')";
```

And this is not throwing any errors but its not loading the partial:

```
return "{{ @include('{$formPartial}') }}";
```

Please note that the partial is working when I'm using in in a template like this:

```
@include('viewsNameSpace::partials._form')
```

but I can't make it work from the directive.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I made it work:

`return "<?php echo view('$formPartial')->render(); ?>";`

Where `$formPartial` is `'viewsNameSpace::partials._form'`.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this question since its post in '16, Laravel now has a blade helper to create a custom `include` directive (since version 5.6.5):

```
Blade::include('viewsNameSpace::path.to.view.file');
```

This is to be added to the `boot()` method of your app service provider. More examples [here](https://laravel-news.com/blade-component-include-aliases).

Comment: Awesome, could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`return "<?php echo view('viewsNameSpace::partials._form')->render(); ?>"`;